# Apache2 Forward proxy with DNS lookup failure for port 443 (SSL) only

Tags: ssl, apache2, mod-proxy

I had to use a forward proxy to limit the access to limited site. I'd tried this before on Apache 1 and all is okay.

Recently, I setup a RHEL6 Linux box and try to use Apache 2 to do the same thing. However, it always reports the following for any SSL site.

For example, it can resolve the IP to access to ibank.standardchartered.com.hk but not for ibank.standardchartered.com.hk:443

Seems it does something DNS lookup in the local proxy server but not in the main proxy.
But when I manually add the ibank.standardchartered.com.hk to local server host table, it works.

```
 - - [25/Apr/2012:17:44:00 +0800] "GET http://www.standardchartered.com.hk/_images/zh/menu1_sub.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
 - - [25/Apr/2012:17:44:00 +0800] "GET http://www.standardchartered.com.hk/_images/zh/menu2_sub.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
 - - [25/Apr/2012:17:44:00 +0800] "GET http://www.standardchartered.com.hk/_images/zh/menu5_sub.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
 - - [25/Apr/2012:17:44:00 +0800] "GET http://www.standardchartered.com.hk/_images/zh/menu6_sub.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
 - - [25/Apr/2012:17:44:00 +0800] "GET http://www.standardchartered.com.hk/_images/zh/menu7_sub.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -
 - - [25/Apr/2012:17:44:00 +0800] "GET http://www.standardchartered.com.hk/_images/zh/menu8_sub.gif HTTP/1.1" 304 -

V2.12
[Wed Apr 25 16:52:34 2012] [error] [client ] proxy: DNS lookup failure for: ibank.standardchartered.com.hk returned by ibank.standardchartered.com.hk:443
[Wed Apr 25 16:53:29 2012] [error] [client ] proxy: DNS lookup failure for: www.google.com returned by www.google.com:443
[Wed Apr 25 17:47:04 2012] [error] [client ] proxy: DNS lookup failure for: ibank.standardchartered.com.hk returned by ibank.standardchartered.com.hk:443
[Wed Apr 25 17:47:04 2012] [error] [client ] proxy: DNS lookup failure for: ibank.standardchartered.com.hk returned by ibank.standardchartered.com.hk:443

v2.4
[Wed Apr 25 16:36:53.387721 2012] [proxy:error] [pid 8024:tid 140494533285632] [client ] AH00898: DNS lookup failure for: ibank.standardchartered.com.hk returned by ibank.standardchartered.com.hk:443
[Wed Apr 25 16:36:53.387932 2012] [proxy:error] [pid 8024:tid 140494533285632] [client ] AH00898: DNS lookup failure for: ibank.standardchartered.com.hk returned by ibank.standardchartered.com.hk:443
```

Here is my configuration:

```
# LoadModule foo_module modules/mod_foo.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
....

ProxyRequests On
ProxyVia On

ProxyRemote * http://proxy.main.com:8080

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Deny from none
Allow from all
</Proxy>
```

It is impossible to put all the internet ssl entry into host table.
Does anyone can solve this?

Thanks

Update on 26-Apr: Finally, I found no solution and change to use Squid.